# magnitude of complex Gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I know X1 and X2 are two iid Gaussian random variables each distributed according to
N(0, σ2), then
X = whole under root of (X1^2 + X2^2) 
is a Rayleigh random variable.And If we take square of this X it gives exponential Random variable. Correct me if I am wrong.

and what happen If we take single Zero mean complex complex gaussian Random variable and takes it magnitude square of real and complex parts whole under root what distribution will that follow ?

Comment: From your first paragraph, this is obvious.

Comment: Dear Yves, Are you saying no matter you take two Random variables and finds magnitude or take one single complex, you take magnitude it gives same Rayleigh RV ?

Comment: How could there be a difference ?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise at all, That is the main reason I am here and asking you nice people, Do i need some sort of transformation of random variable  in doing these things.

Comment: When you write $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, can you tell whether it comes from a pair of real variables or from a complex one ?

Comment: x is real part while y is imaginary in my case, No pairs it's simply one RV

Comment: The magnitude of a complex random variable $z = x + iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are zero-mean Gaussian distributed will still be Rayleigh. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Properties_2

Comment: Thank you so much John Nash, I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: I have one more question, Dear J Nash can we discuss ?@NashJ.

Comment: Yes, go ahead, please!

Comment: If X and Y are correlated exponential Random variables and they are no longer independent(they are Correlated now)  how can I find joint PDF of X and Y ?   I know If they are independent I have to just multiply their PDFs but now what to do? I am about to ask it after 40 minutes but right now can't. @NashJ.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comments, sorry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust pardon please, It comes from complex one.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756646/joint-density-of-two-correlated-normal-random-variables

Comment: Yes this was helpful but mostly we know Gaussian well, Things are different when it comes to other random variables, Thank you so much @NashJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of a complex random variable z=x+iy, where x and y are zero-mean Gaussian distributed will still be Rayleigh, and the square of that magnitude will be exponential.